# I'm trying to "create" an alphabet in PHP, which my gf and I can only understand, but im facing some problems here

Tags: php, html, arrays, string, strsplit

Can someone please help? As it says in the title, im trying "create" an alphabet in PHP, which my gf and I can only understand (it's a little thing that i thought to have with her), but im facing some problems.

I have this code here in HTML and PHP which its purpose is to replace an alphabet letter to some other character.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
    <title>XXX</title>
    <link href="assets/img/favicon.png" rel="icon">
    <link href="assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    @font-face { font-family: "Raleway"; src:url("assets/font/Raleway-Regular.ttf"); }
    ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    }
    .row {
        --bs-gutter-x: 1.5rem;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="font-family: Raleway">
    <main id="main" class="my-0">
        <section class="contact">
            <div class="container d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-12 col-lg-5">
                    <div style="float: none; margin: auto">
                        <form method="post" role="form" class="php-email-form">
                                <div class="row form-group mt-md-0">
                                    <textarea placeholder="AaBbCcDd" class="form-control" name="frase" style="height: 400px;resize: none;"></textarea><br>
                                </div>
                            <div class="row my-3">
                                <div class="col-4 col-sm-6 col-md-8 col-lg-6 form-group mt-md-0">
                                    <button style="padding: 10px" type="submit" class="form-control" name="submit">Traduzir</button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-3 form-group mt-md-0">
                                    <button formaction="descodificador.php" type="submit" class="form-control"><img src="assets/img/reverse.svg" width="15px"></button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-3 form-group mt-md-0" onclick="copiar(); return false;">
                                    <button class="form-control botoes" type="submit"><img src="assets/img/copy.png" width="15px"></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                            <?php
                            if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

                            $frase=$_POST["frase"];

                            if (!empty($frase)) {

                                 Function translate($string) {
                            
                            $alfabeto = array(
                            "a"=>"_","A"=>"_",
                            "b"=>"8","B"=>"8",
                            "c"=>"!","C"=>"!",
                            "d"=>"5","D"=>"5",
                            "e"=>"=","E"=>"=",
                            "f"=>"(","F"=>"(",
                            "g"=>"$","G"=>"$",
                            "h"=>"9","H"=>"9",
                            "i"=>'"',"I"=>'"',
                            "j"=>"1","J"=>"1",
                            "k"=>"+","K"=>"+",
                            "l"=>"@","L"=>"@",
                            "m"=>"2","M"=>"2",
                            "n"=>":","N"=>":",
                            "o"=>"7","O"=>"7",
                            "p"=>"<","P"=>"<",
                            "q"=>")","Q"=>")",
                            "r"=>"4","R"=>"4",
                            "s"=>"/","S"=>"/",
                            "t"=>"*","T"=>"*",
                            "u"=>"0","U"=>"0",
                            "v"=>">","V"=>">",
                            "w"=>";","W"=>";",
                            "x"=>"3","X"=>"3",
                            "y"=>"&","Y"=>"&",
                            "z"=>"6","Z"=>"6",
                            " "=>" ",
                            "?"=>"?",
                            "."=>".",
                            ","=>",",
                            "-"=>"-","ç"=>"{");

                            $saida = array();

                            $entrada = str_split($string);


                            Foreach ($entrada as $key => $value) {


                                $saida[] = $alfabeto[$value];


                            }

                            Return implode('', $saida);
                            
                            }

                            echo "<div id='frase' style='overflow:hidden;word-wrap:break-word'>".translate($frase)."</div>";

                            } else {

                                echo "<font style=color:#c46968>Caracter não suportado</font>";

                            }


                            } else {

                                echo "<font style=color:#68a4c4>Insere o texto</font>";

                            }

                            
                            ?>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var listForRemove = [];
    var listOfUniqe = [];
    $('#frase').each(function () {
    var text = $(this).text().trim();
    if (listOfUniqe.indexOf(text) === -1)
    listOfUniqe.push(text);
    else
    listForRemove.push($(this));
    });
    $(listForRemove).each(function () { $(this).remove(); });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function copiar() {
    if (window.getSelection) {
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(document.getElementById("frase"));
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);
    document.execCommand("copy");
    }
    }
    </script>
    <script src="assets/vendor/aos/aos.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/vendor/glightbox/js/glightbox.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/vendor/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

But when I try to use the letter "ç" it appears this, and i can't really understand why and how to solve it

OUTPUT

```
Warning: Undefined array key "�" in C:\xampp\htdocs\XX\index.php on line 92
Warning: Undefined array key "�" in C:\xampp\htdocs\XX\index.php on line 92
```

Please help me, this is really important to me and my gf.

Comment: Do you mean you want to replace ç by the character {  and encounter errors when you parse the string ?

Comment: what I want to do is like a text converter. I place there a "ç", but it could be something else, like a "á"

Comment: if you want to split a multi-byte string `ç`, you need php >=7.4 and then use [mb_str_split](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-str-split.php) instead https://3v4l.org/BtWhm, then you can match the `ç` with your array key. btw, what your trying to do is called a substitution cipher, its not really secure, but ok for fun